# Argument passing using -D

Tags: java

How to handle the variable passing using `-D`, like `-Dcontext=web` in Java code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can reference the variables you passed on the command line with `-D` like this:

```
String context = System.getProperty("context");
```

So if you passed `-Dcontext=web` then the `context` above will be `web`. Note that you'll get back a `null` if it's not set.