# unable to execute the jar file using java program. i need to pass the file path as a command line argument to the jar file

Tags: java, jar, command, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

The below code not able to write to the files.

i  wrote a program to execute the commands in cmd. Those commands are nothing but executing the java file which is in jar file. This java file which in jar is expecting file path as a command line argument.

Note:- jar file also created by me only.

## here is my java file

```
public class ExcelDriver extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


        File directory = new File("C://Users//kondeti.venkatarao//Documents//Regresion_sheets//custome");
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file: files) {
            System.out.println("\""+file.getAbsolutePath()+"\"");
            if(file.isFile()){
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start java -jar Demo.jar readExcelDemo.Final "+file.getAbsolutePath());
                ExcelDriver.sleep(5000);
            }
        }


            }
}
```

## Here is the jar file code

```
public class Final {

    public static int getExcelColumnNumber(String column) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < column.length(); i++) {
            result *= 26;
            result += column.charAt(i) - 'A' + 1;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static String getExcelColumnName(int number) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        int num = number - 1;
        while (num >=  0) {
            int numChar = (num % 26)  + 65;
            sb.append((char)numChar);
            num = (num  / 26) - 1;
        }
        return sb.reverse().toString();
    }


    void run(File file, File errors, File misMatchs) throws IOException{


        if (file.getName().endsWith(".xlsx") || file.getName().endsWith(".xlsm")) {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            StringBuilder error = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder misMatch = new StringBuilder();
            // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file

            //OPCPackage pkg = OPCPackage.open(file, PackageAccess.READ);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
            int i = 1;
            while (i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets()) {

                // System.out.println(workbook.getNumberOfSheets());
                // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
                XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
                if(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getRawValue().equalsIgnoreCase("fail")){

                    // Iterate through each rows one by one
                    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
                    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Row row = rowIterator.next();
                        // For each row, iterate through all the columns
                        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                            // Check the cell type and format accordingly
                            switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                            /*
                             * case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                             * System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                             * break; case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                             * System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                             * break;
                             */
                            // case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:

                                if (cell.getCellFormula().startsWith("IF("))
                                    if (sheet.getRow(row.getRowNum()).getCell(cell.getColumnIndex()).getRawValue().equals("1")) {

                                        HashSet<Integer> number = new HashSet<Integer>();
                                        ArrayList<String> alphas = new ArrayList<String>();

                                        String formula = sheet.getRow(row.getRowNum()).getCell(cell.getColumnIndex()).toString();
                                        Matcher digitMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(formula);
                                        Matcher alphabetMatcher = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+").matcher(formula);

                                        while (alphabetMatcher.find()) {
                                            if (!alphabetMatcher.group().equals("TYPE"))
                                                alphas.add(alphabetMatcher.group());
                                        }

                                        int countIF = Collections.frequency(alphas, "IF");
                                        int countABS = Collections.frequency(alphas, "ABS");
                                        HashSet<String> alphaSet = new HashSet<String>(alphas);
                                        if (countIF != 5 && countIF != 6)
                                            alphaSet.remove("IF");
                                        if (countABS != 3 && countABS != 4)
                                            alphaSet.remove("ABS");

                                        while (digitMatcher.find()) {
                                            if (!digitMatcher.group().equals("0") && !digitMatcher.group().equals("1") && !digitMatcher.group().equals("01"))
                                                number.add(Integer.parseInt(digitMatcher.group()));
                                        }

                                        ArrayList<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>(number);
                                        ArrayList<String> alphaList = new ArrayList<String>(alphaSet);
                                        System.out.println("alphaSet"+ alphaSet);
                                        System.out.println("numberList"+ numberList);

                                        int rowIndex = numberList.get(0) - 1;
                                        int originalColumnIndex = getExcelColumnNumber(alphaList.get(0)) - 1;
                                        int referenceColumnIndex = getExcelColumnNumber(alphaList.get(1)) - 1;
                                        if (originalColumnIndex > referenceColumnIndex) {
                                            int temp = referenceColumnIndex;
                                            referenceColumnIndex = originalColumnIndex;
                                            originalColumnIndex = temp;
                                        }

                                        // System.out.println(sheet.getRow(row.getRowNum()));
                                        System.out.println("File Name: "+ file.getName());
                                        System.out.println("Sheet Name: "+ sheet.getSheetName());
                                        System.out.println(sheet.getRow(row.getRowNum()).getCell(cell.getColumnIndex()).toString());
                                        if (sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(originalColumnIndex).getCellFormula().equals(""))
                                            System.out.println("please help me out");
                                        System.out.println("Function Name: "+ sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(originalColumnIndex).getCellFormula());
                                        System.out.println("row indext"+ rowIndex);
                                        System.out.println("original column index"+ originalColumnIndex);
                                        System.out.println("ref column index"+ referenceColumnIndex);
                                        /*
                                         * System.out.println("File Name: " +
                                         * file.getName());
                                         * System.out.println("Sheet Name: " +
                                         * sheet.getSheetName());
                                         * System.out.println(cell
                                         * .getCellFormula());
                                         */
                                        if (sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(originalColumnIndex).getCellFormula().contains("qCRA_")&& sheet.getRow(rowIndex)
                                                        .getCell(originalColumnIndex).getRawValue().contains("Error:")) {
                                            error.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                            error.append("File Name: "+ file.getName());
                                            error.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                            error.append("Sheet Name: "+ sheet.getSheetName());
                                            error.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                            error.append("Function Name: "+ sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(originalColumnIndex).getCellFormula());
                                            error.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                            error.append("Cell Number: "+getExcelColumnName(originalColumnIndex+1)+numberList.get(0));
                                            error.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                            error.append("Orginal Value : "+sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(originalColumnIndex).getRawValue());
                                            error.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                            error.append("Reference Value : "+sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(referenceColumnIndex));
                                            error.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                        } else {
                                            misMatch.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                            misMatch.append("File Name: "+ file.getName());
                                            misMatch.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                            misMatch.append("Sheet Name: "+ sheet.getSheetName());
                                            misMatch.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                            misMatch.append("Function Name: "+ sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(originalColumnIndex).getCellFormula());
                                            misMatch.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                            misMatch.append("Cell Number: "+getExcelColumnName(originalColumnIndex+1)+numberList.get(0));
                                            misMatch.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                            misMatch.append("Orginal Value : "+sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(originalColumnIndex).getRawValue());
                                            misMatch.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                            misMatch.append("Reference Value : "+sheet.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(referenceColumnIndex));
                                            misMatch.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                                        }
                                    }
                                break;

                            }
                            cell = null;
                        }
                        row = null;
                    }
                }
                i++;
                fis.close();
                sheet=null;
            }
            workbook=null;
            //FileUtils.writeStringToFile(errors, error.toString(),true);
            //FileUtils.writeStringToFile(misMatchs, misMatch.toString(),true);
            FileWriter errorsFileWriter = new FileWriter(errors,true);
            BufferedWriter errorsBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(errorsFileWriter);
            errorsBufferedWriter.write(error.toString());
            errorsBufferedWriter.flush();
            errorsBufferedWriter.close();

            FileWriter misMatchFileWriter = new FileWriter(misMatchs, true);
            BufferedWriter misMatchesBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(misMatchFileWriter);
            misMatchesBufferedWriter.write(misMatch.toString());
            misMatchesBufferedWriter.flush();
            misMatchesBufferedWriter.close();
        }
}



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String filepath = args[0];//.replace("\" , ", "\\");
            //System.out.println(filepath);
            File directory = new File(filepath);

            File errors = new File("C://Users//kondeti.venkatarao//Documents//Regresion_sheets//Error.txt");
            if(!errors.exists()){
                errors.createNewFile();
            }


            File mismatch = new File("C://Users//kondeti.venkatarao//Documents//Regresion_sheets//Mismatch.txt");
            if(!mismatch.exists()){
                mismatch.createNewFile();
            }

            Final hvd=new Final();
            hvd.run(directory,errors,mismatch);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you...?

Comment: You need to handle the return value of `exec`: store the Process, read the stdout (getInputStream) and stderr (getErrorStream) *in parallel*, `waitFor` the process to exit, and then handle the exit code.

Comment: im executing its not giving any error as well as writing nothing to the file

Comment: @kal i saw your comment for one of the post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123058/passing-on-command-line-arguments-to-runnable-jar    .... here i got the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is what you're passing to the Jar file when calling it. Your Jar file is set to use the first parameter it receives as the directory you want to use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
        String filepath = args[0];//.replace("\" , ", "\\");  // First parameter
        File directory = new File(filepath);
        ....
```

But when you're calling it, you're actually passing in "readExcelDemo.Final" as the first argument, and not what it looks like you want the directory to be:

```
    File directory = new File("C://Users//kondeti.venkatarao//Documents//Regresion_sheets//custome");
    ...
    for (File file: files) {
        ...
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Demo.jar readExcelDemo.Final " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

So your solution would be one of 3 things:

1. Change the Jar file to use the second input (easiest, but not the best)
2. Set your implementation to pass the file path as the first parameter (second easiest, but still not the best)
3. Parameterize what you send the Jar file (e.g. "dir=C:/path/to/dir") and you won't need to have to worry about parameter ordering (hardest, but worth it if you're likely to pass in more parameters)

Hope that helps~

Edit:

PS: I'm assuming you're also not getting any exceptions because it actually is working, however the directory containing your results will be located in your root project directory/readExcelDemo.Final instead of the path it looks like you want it to use

PPS: Also, your execution command doesn't need the first part of `cmd.exe /c start` and should instead be replaced with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Demo.jar readExcelDemo.Final " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

I also took the liberty of replacing that in the first part of my original post.

Comment: java -jar Demo.jar readExcelDemo.Final here "readExcelDemo.Final" means readExcelDemo is a package and Final is a class in Demo.jar file. i think what im doing is correct. is it?

Comment: Yes, that should be for selecting the entry point (but to make things easier, do you need multiple entry points or can you get by with a single one?), and you may want to check this post out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5475076/1426565

Comment: Then you can simplify that even further with: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Demo.jar " + file.getAbsolutePath()); and not worry about fixing the order / parameterizing the calls

Comment: Thanks @Guardanis. what you said is right. my code is working fine.