# Java Application on Linux VS Windows

Tags: java, linux, logging, web-applications, centos

**I developed a website crawler** using Java and it works great on my Windows XP laptop for days and days.

I tested it crawling 5 little websites on a dedicated server with 16Gb RAM, Linux - CentOS and it finishes to crawl in 2 hours, then continues to ping websites to check their uptime but after 2 - 3 hours **it doesn't answer and I have to relaunch it**. I tested it about 10 times and I see the same behaviour.

I force it to write application logs, but I see no exceptions. I print the memory usage and it only uses 50Mb and 100Mb are still available, so I don't think it's a memory problem.

> Memory: Used: 46614 | Free: 91113 | Available: 137728 Total max: 2251776

I use this code to launch it:

```
java -jar myapp.jar -Xmx4000M
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by: "it doesn't asnwer", is the pid alive? Tried to get some insights using jconsole / jvisualvm to profile and see whats wrong? They are right inside the jdk installation and too simple to use.

Comment: To avoid confusion, I would suggest changing the order of your command line options to "java -Xmx4000M -jar myapp.jar". Even if that works the way you have it, it's kinda confusing as trailing arguments could be arguments to the application rather than the JVM. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123058/passing-on-command-line-arguments-to-runnable-jar