# Trying to rewrite code for an assignment to use Command-Line Arguments in Java. I have searched the existing questions

Tags: java, command-line, arguments

I am a new programmer in my first Java class . Here is my code but I am getting an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0 at CmdLine.main(CmdLine.java:13)

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CmdLine{
 public static void main( String [] args ){
   int[] array;
   array = new int [ 10 ];
   for(int counter = 0; counter < array.length;counter++ )
      array[counter]=Integer.parseInt (args[counter]);
      System.out.printf( "%s%8s\n", "Index", "Value" );

      for(int counter = 0; counter < array.length; counter++ )
         System.out.printf( "%5d%8d\n", counter, array[ counter ] );
   }
 }
```

---

Comment: Looks like you are not passing any arguments

Comment: @Andy, let me know if my explanation is useful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to solve this.

**- Methods:**

I know most IDEs allow you to add command line arguments. If you are interested in this, try checking out IntelliJ and this link for further instructions:

[How do you input commandline argument in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066307/how-do-you-input-commandline-argument-in-intellij-idea)

---

There is also another way which is using a jar file,

[Passing on command line arguments to runnable JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123058/passing-on-command-line-arguments-to-runnable-jar/8123107)

Basically, a Jar file works on a terminal command line like this

> java -jar (type_Something)

you can write a file path or a word.

---

**- Explanations:**

When you pass in a command line arguments, the first thing you pass in is for args[0].

Ex.

> java -jar Hello

Hello gets stored in args[0], and then you can use it like this:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String argument1 = args[0];
    }
}
```

But if you now add

> java -jar Hello Friend

Hello is stored in args[0] and Friend in args[1]. Therefore, you can use it like
this:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String argument1 = args[0]; 
        String argument2 = args[1];
    }
}
```

**- Personal Experience:**

I have used the second method, using a jar, before. I believe I had to add a Jar in my IDE before using it on terminal inside my IDE (IntelliJ). I had to send a folder path to my program, and the only way allowed was using a jar to send in command line arguments.