# Is there a way for an executable/runnable jar file to read yml file which can be edited manually?

Tags: java, selenium, yaml, parameter-passing, runnable-jar

I have a selenium maven project, which I converted into a runnable jar. Now I want to parametrize or read certain file which can be edited from outside. My objective is not to build the jar again and again whenever there is a small change in my code. How can this be achieved for an executable jar file.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8123107/6819193

Comment: Thanks I already found the solution. It is the same way you run a normal jar file with properties file.