# Reading data from file given by user

Tags: java, file

I have my program saved in JAR format. I need to read data from two different files given by user using this line: `java -jar app.jar file1.txt file2.txt`. How can I read it? I wrote this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputFileName1 = scan.next().trim();
String inputFileName2 = scan.next().trim();
File input1 = new File(inputFileName1);
Scanner file1 = new Scanner(input1);
File input2 = new File(inputFileName2);
Scanner file2 = new Scanner(input2);
```

It works when I manually write: file1.txt file2.txt, but not with the command line. What's wrong?

Comment: You should use the `args` array in your `main` method to get command line arguments `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing on command line arguments to runnable JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123058/passing-on-command-line-arguments-to-runnable-jar)

Answer (score 2):

When you use command line to send the arguments, you can use `args` to access those arguments. For example, if you run `java yourfile arg0 arg1` on the command line, then you can access `arg0` and `arg1` by using `args[0]` respectively `args[1]` in your code.

So, if you use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File input1 = new File(args[0]);
    Scanner file1 = new Scanner(input1);
    File input2 = new File(inputFileName2);
    Scanner file2 = new Scanner(args[1]);
    ...
}
```

then your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the arguments from the command line through the `args` from your `main` method.

Giving the args out would look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(args[i]);
  }
}
```

You could make something like `File input1 = new File(args[0]);` to get the first argument.